# Rabbit MQ amqplib error "No channels left to allocate"

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

After working the rabbit mq workers in pub sub pattern for some time i am getting an error in creating an channel.

`Error: No channels left to allocate`

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what your problem is. You are most likely not re-using connection and channel instances in your application, but creating new ones for each message. You also don't provide enough information for people to assist - RabbitMQ, Erlang and operating system version, as well as all of your code or at least the parts that deal with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib,
you can use Promise to share a channel while publishing multiple messages

in `message-queue.js`

```
const q = 'tasks';

const open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://localhost');

const channelPromise = open.then((conn) => conn.createChannel());

// Publisher
function publishMessage(message) {
  channelPromise.then((ch) => ch.assertQueue(q)
    .then((ok) => ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(message))))
    .catch(console.warn);
}

// Consumer
open.then((conn) => conn.createChannel())
  .then((ch) => ch.assertQueue(q).then((ok) => ch.consume(q, (msg) => {
    if (msg !== null) {
      console.log(msg.content.toString());
      ch.ack(msg);
    }
  }))).catch(console.warn);

module.exports = {
  publishMessage,
};
```

`some-where.js`

```
messageQueue.publishMessage('hello world')
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of channels you can allocate is negotiated with rabbitmp server. In my server, this value is 2047. You can debug you amqplib/lib/connection.js to get this.

[image]