# after a while i got this error : Error: No channels left to allocate

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

i want to send and save some data in the rabbit; after a while that i run my code and after some sending data into my rabbit i get some error like this: Error: No channels left to allocate

i use from this code several times because i have several data to send into rabbitMQ

```
let open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://localhost:5672')


    open.then(function (conn) {
      return conn.createChannel()
    }).then(function (ch) {
      return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function (ok) {
        ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)))
        return ch.close()
      })
    }).catch(console.warn)
```

Comment: Do you see an error logged by RabbitMQ?

Comment: how can i see the rabitMQ logs?? i see this error on my running command propmt

Comment: @MojaxRazmi - did you manage to solve it? I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are creating new channels when you are publishing messages.

I solved the issue in this question

[Rabbit MQ amqplib error "No channels left to allocate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336128/rabbit-mq-amqplib-error-no-channels-left-to-allocate/66397537#66397537)